# perforce submission files marked by "edit" or "integrate", why?

Tags: linux, perforce

I am using perforce on Linux.

When I did a submission, I found the status of one the submitted files is marked by `edit`.

```
//depot/common/mySpace/branches/mySpace___home_user_mySpace_project_level/myfile.cxx  #  edit
```

But sometimes it is marked by `integrate`.

How do I make this `integrate`?  Are there any benefits of doing this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit surprised people still use perforce. Did you consider migrating to `git` or some other free software version control system?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - It is not easy for organizations which have hundreds of branches, 10 or 100 million files, millions of changelists, and build automation, testing, deployment tools built around perforce to migrate that easily. Not to mention the re-organization of the repos to split it across multiple git repositories. :) Not saying this might be the case for OP, but I've worked with organizations which are facing this problem.

Comment: It is certainly not easy (and migration of VCS is not easy, even from `svn` to `git`), but it probably could be considered.

Comment: While not mentioned here, part of OP's system is on OpenVMS. Perforce is the last great SCM to really be available there.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Try doing game development with git. From what I've read, it's just not suited for it. http://enemyhideout.com/2016/06/why-git-is-not-good-for-games/  git isn't the be-all-end-all of source control for every single situation.

Answer (score 6):

- If you make changes to a file (without running `p4 integrate`) which already exists under version control, and submit the changes it would be marked as an `edit`
- If you integrate a file or set of files from one perforce location to another, it would be marked as an `integrate` as long as you do not make any further changes before submitting.
- If you integrate and then edit the file before submitting, perforce would mark it as an `edit`.

Honestly, there is no pro/con in the file being marked as integrate or edit. There would still be valid integration history between the files that could be used with tools like `p4 filelog`, `p4 annotate` etc. in both the cases.

In addition to `edit`, `integrate`, there are also `add`, `branch`, and `delete`.

- perforce marks a file as an `add` when it is newly added.
- perforce marks a file as a `branch` when it was integrated for the first time from a location and the file does not yet exist in the destination.
- perforce marks a file as a `delete` when it is deleted.

Answer (score 5):

"edit" and "integrate" indicate what operation Perforce thinks you are doing on your files.  If you use the "p4 edit" command to update a file, it will be marked with "edit".  If you use "p4 integrate" or "p4 branch" to branch or merge files, they will be marked with "integrate".  There are no benefits to either tag, they are set by Perforce depending on what command you use.